# install4j app launcher not working on macOS 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: install4j

I'm having a problem after upgrading to the install4j 8. App is notarized and runs fine on macOS 10.11 through 10.15, but I get this error on macOS 10.10 (Yosemite):

> An internal error occurred (error code: Could not load JRE from The bundle "Java SE 8" couldn't be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources..)

The Console shows these messages which seem to indicate that the JavaApplicationStub signature cannot be validated:

```
12/8/19 6:03:53.000 PM kernel[0]: AMFI: Error! There is a null code directory pointer. This is an unexpected condition.
12/8/19 6:03:53.000 PM kernel[0]: proc 618: load code signature error 4 for file "JavaApplicationStub"
12/8/19 6:03:53.000 PM kernel[0]: AMFI: Error! There is a null code directory pointer. This is an unexpected condition.
12/8/19 6:03:53.000 PM kernel[0]: AMFI: Error! There is a null code directory pointer. This is an unexpected condition.
12/8/19 6:03:53.123 PM JavaApplicationStub[618]: int launcher_main(int, char **) [Line 1047] Could not load JRE from The bundle “Java SE 8” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources..: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff915b003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ba0976e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff915afeed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   JavaApplicationStub                 0x000000010f908fc4 -[Launcher launch] + 660
    4   JavaApplicationStub                 0x000000010f909c85 launcher_main + 645
    5   JavaApplicationStub                 0x000000010f909df2 main + 34
    6   JavaApplicationStub                 0x000000010f901764 start + 52
)
```

For now, I'm telling users on 10.10 or older to use the previous version of my app, which was packaged using install4j 7, but I'm hoping for a solution from ej-technologies here.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted so fast. What other info should I provide?

Comment: Is this a folder archive bundle? This will be fixed in 8.0.3, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already working.

Comment: It's a Single Bundle Archive.

Comment: Anyway, please ask us for the current build.